# Add multiple elements of same name and type to XSD1.0

Tags: xml, xsd

Here  is my xml -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<choices xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema2.xsd">
    <choice id="c1" text="text 1" description="description1" isCommentRequired="true"></choice>
    <choice id="c2" text="text 2" description="description2" isCommentRequired="false"></choice>
</choices>
```

I would like to develop schema for the same and my attempt is as follows -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="XMLSchema2" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema2.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema2.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
    <xs:element name="choices">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="choice" type="choiceType">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:boolean">
                                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" fixed="c1"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="text" type="xs:string" fixed="text 1"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="isCommentRequired" type="xs:boolean" fixed="true"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" fixed="description1"/>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="choice" type="choiceType">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:boolean">
                                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" fixed="c2"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="text" type="xs:string" fixed="text 2"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="isCommentRequired" type="xs:boolean" fixed="false"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" fixed="description2"/>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="choiceType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:boolean">
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:attribute name="text" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:attribute name="isCommentRequired" type="xs:boolean"/>
                <xs:attribute name="nextQuestionId" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

I am getting warning *The type attribute cannot be present with either simpleType or complexType.*

Constraints -

1. xsd1.0
2. I would like choice elements to have these fixed attributes in schema and in xml and not be changed by the user.

Does anyone have any idea how to correct the schema please?

Comment: why do you have this line twice in the schema :  <xs:element name="choice" type="choiceType">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong here.

Firstly, the thing it's actually complaining about is

```
<xs:element name="choice" type="choiceType">
   <xs:complexType>
```

You can define the type of an element either by reference to a named global type, or with a local inline `<complexType>` declaration, but it makes no sense to do both.

Secondly, there is no sense in repeating the element declaration with name="choice". If it will always occur exactly twice, write

```
<xs:element name="choice" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2">
```

Thirdly, you've defined the type as an extension of `xs:boolean` (extended with attributes), but in your instance document the `<choice>` elements are empty (they only have attributes, no content).

Comment: Hello @MichealKay,
Thanks for your reply.

Reply as by your points.

1. Yes it makes no sense. The schema declaration is wrong and I want to know how to correct it.  But more in reply to your second point.

2. In my case, each choice has an id and other attributes and they must be same. User can only record their response which is capture as true/false. So one validation of the xml is that the attributes of the choice node are fixed as mentioned in XML. Having these attributes as fixed in schema will make the validation easier.

3. You are correct, content needs to be and will be set.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't spot the "fixed" attributes. This runs against the "Element Declarations Consistent" rule in XSD, which says that if two elements are siblings and have the same name, then they must have the same type.

Comment: So basically it can not done with xsd 1.0, is that right?

Comment: Yes, you need XSD 1.1 assertions for this kind of constraint.